# Springboot parsing HTTP HTTPS

Tags: spring-boot, https

I have found such error message in my Springboot app logs:

```
Oct 20 14:22:14 ip-10-0-78-113 web: 2020-10-20 14:22:14.388 INFO 3802 — [nio-8081-exec-5] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor : Error parsing HTTP request header
Oct 20 14:22:14 ip-10-0-78-113 web: Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
Oct 20 14:22:14 ip-10-0-78-113 web: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
...
```

I got to know, that its probably because somebody / some app is calling my endpoint with use of HTTPS instead of HTTP. I was able to log those requests by including in properties:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web: trace
logging.level.org.apache: trace
```

Now I have received unparsed text, something like this:

```
 Received [ ÷  ó÷=EVq&GÅµH¡à}C¶vÓÂíÿ@,¾ )L /ð^  w» e<Ú5~ñ¨7ëÌaÒ*l×eÂ $À/À+À0À,Ì©Ì¨À ÀÀ
À   / 5 
            localhost   ÿ   
   3 & $   ¬·lä¹]Ö·a6ððòvcd»[7Ûj V -  + ]
```

Is it possible to decode/decrypt it, and find out what the actual API call was?

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem & make it working by using http:// instead of https://